# Pass Parameter(s) from Access Variable to SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, vba, variables, stored-procedures, parameters

I am trying to pass variables/parameters from an Access table to a stored procedure in SQL Server using an ADODB connection. I am pulling the variables in Access from and Access query (so I’m trying to pass a variable that is updated each time the code is executed). I am getting the following error message when trying to pass the variables below in the Access VBA Code:

> Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.

I am new to this kind of coding. Could someone please provide some direction on how to pass variables (a result of an Access query) to a stored procedure, and then call those variables in the stored procedure?

Access VBA code:

```
        '''CREATE LINKED TABLE THAT PULLS FROM TBL_STATEMENT_MASTER IN SQL
        ''variables to pass to get dFileRE
        '' (1) stateDate
        stateDate = getItem("select distinct paydate from update_statement_master_re")
        '' (2) stateNGN
        stateNGN = getItem("select distinct deal_code from update_statement_master_re")

            user = GetUser()

        '' Connect to Data Source - Securities DB - SQL Server
            Set dbconn = New ADODB.Connection
            dbconn.ConnectionString = "driver=SQL Server;server=R7SQL1;database=SecuritiesDB;trusted_connection=YES"
            dbconn.Open dbconn.ConnectionString
            Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
            cmd.ActiveConnection = dbconn

        '' Set CommandText equal to the stored procedure name (spStatementCheck)
            cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
            cmd.CommandText = "spStatementCheck"
            cmd.NamedParameters = True 'paramStatementCheck'

'' THIS IS THE PART OF THE CODE THAT IS CRASHING – I AM NOT SURE HOW TO CALL THESE VARIABLES
            cmd.Parameters.Append _
                cmd.CreateParameter("@SPstateNGN", adVarChar, adParamInput, 0, "& stateNGN &")
            cmd.Parameters.Append _
                cmd.CreateParameter("@SPstateDate", adDate, adParamInput, 0, "& stateDate &")
```

SQL Server stored procedure code:

```
     USE [SecuritiesDB_TEST]
      GO
     SET ANSI_NULLS ON
      GO
     SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
      GO

     ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spStatementCheck]
     @SPstateNGN as nvarchar(25),
     @SPstateDate as datetime

      AS

-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;


     -- Insert statements for procedure here

       INSERT INTO UPDATE_Statement_Master_Check ( NGN_Full, [Date], [DESCRIPTION], AMOUNT,     NGN_SHORT, Series, FileDate, EffectiveDate, ActualDate, [Source], ID )
        SELECT tbl_Statement_Master.NGN_Full, tbl_Statement_Master.[Date], 
       tbl_Statement_Master.[DESCRIPTION], 
       tbl_Statement_Master.AMOUNT, 
       tbl_Statement_Master.NGN_SHORT, 
       tbl_Statement_Master.Series, 
       tbl_Statement_Master.FileDate, 
       tbl_Statement_Master.EffectiveDate, 
       tbl_Statement_Master.ActualDate, 
       tbl_Statement_Master.[Source], 
       tbl_Statement_Master.ID
       FROM tbl_Statement_Master
       where tbl_Statement_Master.[Date] <> @SPstateDate
       and tbl_Statement_Master.NGN_Full  = @SPstateNGN
       and tbl_statement_master.FileDate = (Select distinct max(filedate) from tbl_statement_master
       where [DATE] = @SPstateDate and NGN_Full = @SPstateNGN);
```

Comment: I might be missing something here but the `GetItem` lines would return multiple values and you are trying to pass these multiple values to the `CreateParameter` calls.  Wouldn't you be looking to have a loop in there somewhere to loop through every record and execute the stored procedure based on the parameter values in that record.
I don't understand the `"& stateNGN &"` part of creating the parameter either.  In the past I simply place the variable in that argument without the quotes or the ampersand.

Comment: The **GetItem** will only return one value. I used **stateNGN** and **stateDate** as those variables need to be updated each time the code is executed, rather than hard coding the variables.

Comment: Point taken on `GetItem`, the second point was about `CreateParameter("@SPstateNGN", adVarChar, adParamInput, 0, stateNGN)`, just removing the quotes and ampersands as whatever value is held in the variable is passed in as the parameter value.

Comment: Great, thank you that seems to have worked. Does the stored procedure code look correct? I am not sure if the parameters will actually get passed to the stored procedure. Is there a way to check that they are being passed correctly?

Comment: I'm not going to advise you on debugging SQL Server stored procedures but I would test either appending to a disposable table and checking the number of records added, then running an identical query in SQL Sever directly and comparing.  Alternatively compare the before and after.  Alternatively return the `@@ROWCOUNT`.  I don't see why it wouldn't pass the correct values through.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to test and make sure the variables were being passed by creating the temp table and running the two queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to add your parameters you only need to pass the variables themselves into the call.

```
'' THIS IS THE PART OF THE CODE THAT IS CRASHING – I AM NOT SURE HOW TO CALL THESE VARIABLES            
cmd.Parameters.Append _
    cmd.CreateParameter("@SPstateNGN", adVarChar, adParamInput, 0, "& stateNGN &")
cmd.Parameters.Append _
    cmd.CreateParameter("@SPstateDate", adDate, adParamInput, 0, "& stateDate &")
```

The problem is with the 2 values you are passing in as parameters: `"& stateNGN &"` and `"& stateDate &"`.  In this instance you don't have to do anything fancy with your variables as they already contain the values you want to pass to the stored procedure, and the `CreateParameter` call will handle them for you.

So just change those calls to:

```
cmd.Parameters.Append _
    cmd.CreateParameter("@SPstateNGN", adVarChar, adParamInput, 0, stateNGN)
cmd.Parameters.Append _
    cmd.CreateParameter("@SPstateDate", adDate, adParamInput, 0, stateDate)
```

Note that you could also create the parameter in one step and then assign a value to it in a subsequent step, as opposed to the all-in-one approach taken above.  Further examples on `CreateParameter` can be found on various Stack Overflow threads and on the MSDN website.